# Can I solve the separation problem efficiently, when I have access to an optimization oracle?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

Assume I have given a convex feasible set $X$ and I have an oracle that can optimize some linear objective function $c$ over $X$. Assume that I have given a point $r$.

I want to solve the separation problem to decide if either $r \in X$ or I want a hyperplane that separates $r$ from $X$. Is there some practical algorithm for this given the optimization oracle?

Comment: You haven't stated that $X$ is convex. If $X$ is not convex and $r \notin X$,, there may not be a hyperplane separating $r$ from $X$.

Comment: Yes sorry $X$ is convex

Answer (score 3):

You can minimize any convex function $f$ over $X$ using the [Frank-Wolfe algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Wolfe_algorithm).
In particular, this will give you valid dual bounds at every iteration.

[Note: the FW algorithm assumes that you can minimize *any* linear function over $X$]

Consider the problem
\begin{align}
Z^{*} = &\min_{x}\quad\|x - r\|^{2}\\
&\text{s.t.} \quad x \in X
\end{align}

Assume that $r \notin X$, i.e., $Z^{*} > 0$, and apply Frank-Wolfe to the above problem.
After some iteration, you will get a positive dual bound, i.e., you know that $Z^{*} \geq Z_{\text{dual}} > 0$, which will prove that $r \notin X$.

You can then deduce a separation hyperplane from the ball centered at $r$ of radius $Z^{*}$ by taking a tangent at $x^{*}$, where $x^{*}$ is an optimal solution of the above problem.

Comment: thanks, that looks pretty cool!

Comment: If $X$ is a polytope, can i converge such that the separation hyerplane becomes a facet at some point?

Comment: And didnt you mean the ball is centered around the current iterate? Or maybe can you expand the last point?

Comment: Sorry, I made a slight typo. Once you have $Z_{dual} > 0$, you know that $r \notin X$. To get a separating hyperplane you can use an _optimal solution_ provided by FW. I've edited the answer.

Comment: My gut tells me there should be a way to deduce a separating hyperplane as soon as you have $Z_{dual} > 0$, but I did not manage to prove that in the 10min I spent thinking about it.